# laravel 8 markdown email image not showing

Tags: laravel, email, markdown, laravel-8

I'm dispatching a markdown email using the Laravel's mailable class.

Here's the following code for the mailable.

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;
use App\traits\Mail\RecordMailTrait;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Laravel\Spark\Invitation;
class ExistingUserCompanyInviteMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels, RecordMailTrait;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $invite;
    public $inviter;
    public $view = 'email.invitation-to-current-user';
    public function __construct(Invitation $invite, User $inviter)
    {
        $this->invite = $invite;
        $this->inviter = $inviter;
    }
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $invitation = $this->invite;
        $view = $this->view;
        $to = $this->to[0]['address'];
        $sent_by_email = $this->inviter->email;
        $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use($invitation, $view, $to, $sent_by_email){
            $message->view = $view;
            $message->sent_to_email = $to;
            $message->sent_by_email = $sent_by_email;
            $message->mailable_type = Invitation::class;
            $message->mailable_id = $invitation->id;
        });
        return $this->markdown($this->view,['invitation' => $this->invite, 'inviter' => $this->inviter, 'entity' => $this->invite->team->name, 'url' => url('/home/invitations')])->subject("Invitation");
    }
}
```

I get the email in my inbox, with the correct text and styling, however not the image, it doesn't load as it should.

Here's the code for the HTML:

```
<tr>
<td class="header">
<a href="{{ $url }}" style="display: inline-block;">
<img src="{{ asset('/img/logo.svg')}}" class="logo" alt="logo1">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is the URL I get from the image in the sent email:

https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8oh80_LJVyfK50ZObX23alnA8vhDzf3vXWJC_kHVgccnfzs-zSher-TbH9fO4RcDWjTQ5s8c_q3V6qc=s0-d-e1-ft#http://core-hosp.test/img/logo.svg

[logo does not show (image of email)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgDiN.png)

Comment: What do you expect? That link is broken: "404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /proxy/8oh80_LJVyfK50ZObX23alnA8vhDzf3vXWJC_kHVgccnfzs-zSher-TbH9fO4RcDWjTQ5s8c_q3V6qc=s0-d-e1-ft was not found on this server. That’s all we know." Make sure you're using a URL that actually points to something.

Comment: @Chris obviously that's not the URL being used in the view HTML.

Comment: @miken32, why "obviously"? OP hasn't told us anything about how images are hosted for this application. Hosting images on cloud services is pretty common.

Comment: Can you add the section of HTML from the email that matches the section of your view included above?

Comment: Gmail might block the image, which is a user preference, but also the URL for the image is local `http://core-hosp.test/...` so it will never show up. Use something like [mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) to test your emails, but also make sure the image URL is publicly accessible on the internet, not just from your local machine.